# Unable to redirect from login page after authentication with JAAS

Tags: java, servlets, redirect, jetty, jaas

After the user has logged in I want to make a **redirect** if `/login` is accessed again, so that the user cannot access the login form if he/she is **already authenticated**.

I am using **Jetty 8** and I found in the [FormAuthenticator.java:168](http://archive.eclipse.org/jetty/8.0.0.M2/xref/org/eclipse/jetty/security/authentication/FormAuthenticator.html#168) method `validateRequest` that if the user accesses the login or error page, the user is **never authenticated, eventhough that might be the case**

```
if (isLoginOrErrorPage(URIUtil.addPaths(request.getServletPath(),request.getPathInfo())))
    return Authentication.NOT_CHECKED;
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet? I'm having the exact same problem with jetty-maven. I haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem was fixed on 2012-08-07. I think Jetty does not work here as intended. For that reason I [filed a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=386714) regarding the redirection behavior. Have a look at the latest Jetty 8, it should work now for you, respectively have a look at the [fix](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-8/jetty-security/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/security/authentication/FormAuthenticator.java#L191).

Comment: Wow! I'm very surprised. Mevos's solution worked for me though, I was not using Jetty 8.

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with the problem that you described for a while...

I tried to use the API of the session, the request and the response to do a redirect when the user is already logged in, but the authentication data for the user is apparently not available from the login page when using Jetty.

I'm totally new to JSP and Jetty (I'm using it for a class assignment), but I made a solution that worked fairly well, even thought it's not the ideal solution.

First, I made a small bypass by adding a variable in my login page to see if the page had already been loaded, by using the following JSP:

```
<%
if(session.getAttribute("loginLoadedOnce") == "true")
{
    response.sendRedirect("/redirect.jsp");
}
else
{
    session.setAttribute("loginLoadedOnce", "true");
}
%>
```

That way, if the attribute is set incorrectly it will let the user try to login. Otherwise, it will redirect to the redirect page. The redirect page will have the user data available and it will be able to see if a user has certain roles.

The JSP code for the redirect page was like this:

```
<%
if(request.isUserInRole("admin"))
{
    String url = response.encodeRedirectURL("admin/AdminPage.jsp");
    response.sendRedirect(url);
}
else if(request.isUserInRole("accounting"))
{
    String url = response.encodeRedirectURL("/accounting/Mainpage.jsp");
    response.sendRedirect(url);
}
else
{
    // Here the user has no role that we are aware of.
    session.setAttribute("loginLoadedOnce", "false"); // stop redirect loop.
    response.sendRedirect("/login.jsp");
}
%>
```

Here we check the roles of the user and we redirect to the correct page for the role.

As it is right now, the user will have to logout before he can go back to the login page. Every tentative to go back to the login page will end up redirecting, even using the "Back" button of the browser.

Hoping this will help somebody.